# Disable FLASH (swf) caching

Tags: flash

On Mac both chrome & firefox are caching swf files so the new file never shows up when it's been updated.

In chrome & firefox i've tried disabling cache but nothing works. i've tried the pragma, expires, cache-control (no-cache, no-store) options but somehow the swf is still cached.

Does the Flash Player have a cache? If so how do i disable it for testing?

Answer (score 1):

Add a random number or a timestamp or something as the query parameter to the URL of the SWF file. For example:

```
/path/to/my.swf?t=1371226488
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
var path = "/path/to/my.swf?"+time;
```

Comment: This is the same answer as above. This cache busting technique isn't working in chrome for me